# Direct flight connection between LAX and LGW in COVID era?

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, lax, lgw

Is there any?

Previously I used mainly Norwegian to fly to Gatwick, but it has shut down most of the flights till December. What may be the substitute?

Non-direct are also appreciated (1 stop) and also I am considering other US cities. Through engines, I found only 1-stop Turkish Airlines flight (LAX-IST-LGW), but it seems rather pricey, about $900.

Comment: When do you want the flight? Right now? i.e. June/July?

Comment: June-July-August, anywhen in next 3 months

Answer (score 5):

Things are in a rapid state of flux and could change on short notice, but, as of this writing, [it looks like](https://flightaware.com/live/findflight?origin=ZLN&destination=KLAX) British Airways and Virgin Atlantic are each operating one nonstop flight daily from London Heathrow to LAX. There do not appear to be any flights operating from Gatwick to anywhere in North America. Traveling from Gatwick to Heathrow before flying is likely to be significantly easier than taking any combination of flights out of Gatwick, but it is also important to consider in these times if it might be smarter (for the benefit of both the traveler and the community to which they'd be flying) not to travel at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like flights are getting more expensive after COVID, see this new question here as to why:

- [Why are flights getting more expensive as traveling returns back to normal?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/157820/105447)

The best I managed to do is get the price down to £788 but that is with a lengthy stop-over:

> [image]

([link to flight](https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/lax/lond/200628/200705/config/13416-2006280700--32317-1-13554-2006290810%7C13554-2007051215--32480-1-13416-2007051949?adultsv2=1&cabinclass=economy&childrenv2=&inboundaltsenabled=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&preferdirects=false&rtn=1&priceSourceId=&priceTrace=202006190248*I*LAX*STN*20200628*skyp*DY%7C202006190248*I*LHR*LAX*20200705*skyp*EI&qp_prevCurrency=GBP&qp_prevPrice=766&qp_prevProvider=ins_month))

Comment: It's not Gatwick unfortunately

Comment: @Suncatcher Getting from Heathrow to Gatwick is quite easy

Comment: I'm searching a flight for a senior person, so moving between airports can be a problem for him

Comment: @Suncatcher Why Gatwick? Is there some other part to this proposed itinerary?

Comment: Because only Gatwick has direct connection with Belarus, as I said before every layover is hard for senior

Comment: @Suncatcher it would probably be easier to look up the full itinerary from LAX to the final destination, this would probably give more options and reduce the number of connections.

Comment: @Suncatcher you can find flights from LAX to MSQ via IST (very long overnight connection), AMS, CDG...

Comment: `LAX to MSQ via IST` that what I mentioned in the question, Turkishes makes very long layover. Thanks for AMS suggestion, I found a good flight with KLM